# Undefined method 'status' for nil:nilclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, nomethoderror

Ok weird error. Everything was working fine.. and now its not.

Currently I have a simple many to one association.

Route is set up like this:

```
resources :apps do
  resources :forms
end
```

App:

```
has_many :forms
```

Form:

```
belongs_to :app
```

Forms_controller index action:

```
def index
  @app = App.find(params[:app_id])
  @forms = @app.forms
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @forms }
  end
end
```

I've taken every bit of code/html out of the forms.html.erb layout file so it should be rendering a blank page.

Instead I'm getting this error:

undefined method `status' for nil:NilClass

status isn't even defined anywhere in my app

help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is what is displayed in my development.log file

```
Started GET "/apps/4/forms" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-05 23:14:16 -0700
  Processing by FormsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"app_id"=>"4"}
  [1m[36mApp Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "apps".* FROM "apps" WHERE "apps"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "4"]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "forms" WHERE "forms"."app_id" = 4
0
  [1m[36mForm Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "forms".* FROM "forms" WHERE "forms"."app_id" = 4[0m
Rendered forms/index.html.erb within layouts/forms (1.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 37ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `status' for nil:NilClass):
```

Comment: Can you please post the error stacktrace?

Comment: The error message is useless when there is no info about where the error comes from. Check the full error message and show us all the lines you received. You may need to look into the logfile - most probably: 'log/development.log'.

Comment: I'll post the exact message when I get home, but from memory the error log said rendered /layouts/forms.html.erb and then immediately after had an internal server error. I can put a logger inside the controller action and it logs just fine, but there wasn't a line number like there normally is when you get an error like this... just an internal server error.

Comment: Added in internal server error message

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue - I had a method named 'response' that something internal to Rails was calling 'status' on and it similarly bailed without a stack trace to speak of.

With things named 'app' and 'forms' you might be running into something similar.

Answer (score 0):

**@app** was not found, you can fetch forms within *try*

```
def index
  @app = App.find(params[:app_id])
  @forms = @app.try(:forms)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @forms }
  end
end
```

If your template handles the @app, and it's important to have it, better to handle the exception:

```
def index
  @app = App.find!(params[:app_id]) # raise an exception until find
  @forms = @app.forms
rescue
  flash[:error] = "App not found!"
end
```

Comment: AFAIK `find(an_id)` throws an exception if the record is not found. Are you sure the method `find!` exists?

Comment: yes, just use **#find**. *find* raises the exception until find a record, I thought about *create* / *create!* difference.

Comment: I have just found that in newest Rails the [dynamic finders](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) also understand the exclamation mark, so you can do `find_by_name!`. A nice addition, I would say. :)

Comment: The app is found I can log its name with logger inside the controller action without any trouble. Although point taken about the exception.

Answer (score 0):

First, please check log/development.log or on browser.  It should help you where the error hapened.

Next, what is params value?  Check log/development.log.  It may look like the followings:

```
...
Processing FormsController#index (for 127.0.1.1 at YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss) [GET]
Parameters: {...}
...
```

Comment: Thank for your development.log.  It looks "App.find..." is OK, but error happens at rendering the view.  Does the forms/index.html.erb (or partial in it, or any helper which the erb file uses) has 'status' method?  If yes like 'x.status', x should be nil so that why the error happened.  By the way, is your routing (resources :apps do esources :forms end) correct? do you really need nested resource routing?

Comment: Another comment.  Maybe (at-mark)app is bad.  When we see RoR source in gems directory, there (at-mark)app variable in Rack and ActionController.  What happens when you change (at-mark)app to another instance variable like (at-mark)my_app and use it in the view?  (BTW, at-mark here means @ to avoid this site's comment format)

Answer (score 0):

For internal server errors your application could not be started properly.  You should check your server error log.  It may give you insight as to what the problem is.  If you, or a team member as the case may be, didn't make any changes that broke the application then you should check with your host.  Perhaps they made changes to your environment that are causing an error.

Comment: Currently just using a dev machine and webrick... but I'll dig into this more.